# C# destructors and GC not really solving problems compared to C++ destructors

Tags: c#, c++, garbage-collection, c++-cli, destructor

**EDIT**: This question is meant for comparison between C# and C++ implementations. There is no need to flip dramatic when having a discussion. I personally prefer to develop in C# anyway.

Assume I have the following class:

```
class Foo {
            FileStream f;
            public Foo() {
                f = File.Open("somefile.txt", FileMode.Open);
            }
            ~Foo() {
                f.Close();
            }
        }
```

Then I am calling the following in Main:

```
static void Main(){
    doSomething();
    // this one creates an exception, file in use
    doSomething();
}
static void doSomething(){
    Foo f = new Foo();
}
```

In C++, this code will work just fine:

```
    class Foo {
public:
    std::ofstream ofs;
    Foo() { ofs = ofstream("somefile.txt"); }
    ~Foo() { ofs.close(); }
};

void doSomething() {
    Foo f();
}

int main() {
    doSomething();
    doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

As when the first `doSomething()` goes out of scope, the first object calls its destructor and closes the file.

In C# this will always throw an exception saying the file is being used by another process. Obviously the destructor has not been called.

Referring to MSDN page about destructors [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx), it confuses whoever reads it and makes them think this is actually a destructor. While it is in fact a finializer called by GC whenever GC decides to call it, which is out of my hand.

Yes, I can implement `IDisposeable` but I do not want every programmer that uses my library to remember calling `Dispose()` or he will have unhandled exceptions.

I can call `GC.Collect()` between the two `doSomething()` methods and no exception will be thrown. Yet again, this will be similar to `Dispose()` and the user of the library will have to remember it. Not mentioning the zillion warnings from MS telling people PLEASE DO NOT USE `GC.Collect()` !!

So my question is, if MS wanted to have destructors like C++ does, do they have to only call the Garbage Collector every time a method goes out of scope? Or would it be more complicated for them? What type of complications for such design would there be?

Also, if it was simple, why don't they do it?

Moreover, is there a way to force the destructor in C# to be called upon going out of scope?

EDIT:

I was looking at the C++/CLI implementation, and interestingly the keyword `gcnew` allows exactly what I want to happen for the C#. So the answer really lies within that implementation. As in their documentation, when the managed object goes out of scope, the GC is called and so the destructor of the managed object is called. And that does not force the user to `Dispose` the object manually.

That answers the question about how "hard" would it be for MS to make GC work similarly when an object goes out of scope. It just automatically calls `GC.Collect()` which forces the GC to call the destructor similar to what happens in C++.

Comment: "In C++, this code will work just fine" is a complete lie, since the code is not even valid C++.

Comment: Even if one were to read the code extremely generously and ignore all the syntax errors, the code would still not work the way you think in C++, since no destructors would be called, since the lifetime of "f" is manual.

Comment: `is a complete lie`.. Well it is obvious I'm talking about a similar code, maybe like `ofstream` or something. I am asking for apples and you are talking about oranges. That is not the point of the question and you know it is not. Instead of playing smart try to look at the question

Comment: What are the reasons as to why you prefer that consumers of your library not wrap allocations of the class in a `using` block?

Comment: You need to ask Microsoft why they did something, if you want to know why they did something. All you'll get here is opinions. I will say, it's a complete mistake to view C# destructors as anything like C++ destructors. They are completely different. C# doesn't have stack-allocated classes, and so the idea of "going out of scope" just doesn't apply. The only thing that matters is if the heap-allocated object is reachable, according to the rules of the GC.

Comment: @PeterDuniho This is what my question is about, how complicated for MS would it be to implement destructors that work similar, not exactly, as C++ destructors

Comment: Different languages, different behaviours. The non-deterministic behaviour of the garbage collector (you don't know when it will run, just that it will run)  plays unholy hell on RAII, so if you want a resource released at a given time, you damn well have to do it yourself and not count on the destructor. On the upside most memory management is fire-and-forget. A trade off.

Comment: You might want to read Eric Lippert's blog post about finalizers in C#  https://ericlippert.com/2015/05/18/when-everything-you-know-is-wrong-part-one/

Comment: And [Raymond Chen's piece on garbage collectors](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203). I was going to write an answer, but why bother? Mr. Chen already did.

Comment: As far as I know, Disposing object and System.GC.Collect() don't release memory immediately but the time of release is decided automatically. However, I tried System.GC.Collect(0, GCCollectionMode.Forced); and the results were different and satisfied.

Comment: @KerrekSB Happy now? Both codes tested and working, will you focus on the point now?

Comment: @user4581301 That is exactly my point, which is frustrating me in C#, I have no control over the GC and no expectation. I have to force everything myself while in C++ I can just implement the destructor that is automatically called upon going out of scope

Comment: _"how complicated for MS would it be to implement destructors that work similar"_ -- not complicated per se, but contrary to their entire design goal. _" I can just implement the destructor that is automatically called upon going out of scope"_ -- there is already extensive discussion on learning the idioms required moving from a true RAII language to something like C#. C# finalizers are backup for dealing with buggy code; your code design shouldn't rely on them in the first place, so when they execute should be immaterial to you. Write your code correctly, and it just won't matter.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Well, I am not talking that they should change the design, I am just wondering whether providing such capability would help programmers avoiding some problems or not

Comment: @AmmarSalman: [Really tested](https://ideone.com/6TxoND)? :-) But I do appreciate the effort.

Comment: The core of your question is why not allow garbage collection and manual memory management. What follows is pure opinion: You don't want to have both paradigms concurrently. People will screw it up. They will expect the GC when they shouldn't and delete when they shouldn't. It's better to have one rule to rule them all so that there is no ambiguity. It's interesting that Delphi does allow you to mix and match GC and manual to a degree and C# doesn't and Anders Hejlsberg was god-emperor of both languages.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, really tested and prove my point.

Comment: @user4581301 I am myself a fan of C#, but whenever an argument is made against it, it is all about the limited capabilities compared to C++, and it is hard fight those arguments because it is in fact much less capable than C++

Comment: _"it is in fact much less capable than C++"_ -- that you believe that demonstrates that you know too little about what makes a programming language a programming language to sufficiently grasp any discussion comparing and contrasting a pair of languages. In terms of final results, there is literally nothing that C++ can do that C# can't do. The languages are radically different, and provide very different programming experiences, emphasizing different priorities and requiring different competencies from the programmer. But ultimately, they both are equally capable.

Comment: `there is literally nothing that C++ can do that C# can't do` Good luck programming hardware with C#. Good luck creating new operating systems in C#. Good luck with programming on Linux with C#. That you believe C# can do just as good as C++ demonstrates you know too little of how each of these languages is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have surmised, C# does not have deterministic destructors and comparing this to C++ is always going to be "apples to oranges".  Further, implementing a destructor on a C# class will cause the GC cleanup of an instance of that class even less deterministic since the GC will put any instance with a destructor into a list to be handled by a separate thread at some later time.

If you want deterministic disposal of an instance, implement the `IDisposable` interface/pattern. That's what it is there for.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I don't want to force the users of the library to use `Dispose()` on my instance or they will have errors and errors

Comment: @AmmarSalman You can have both.  Then the user has the ability to do immediate clean up or they will just have to deal with the will of the GC.

Comment: Understood. The only reason to force the users of your class to care about lifetime management is when they might want to perform multiple actions with it during its lifetime -- and in that case it is the users responsibility since only they will know when they are done.  If each method is atomic you only need to handle the creation and disposal within the method.  Perhaps by creating a separate internal or private class that does the actual work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a C# issue. Your class should handle the opening and closing properly.

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        string someText = "someText";
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("myfile.txt"))
        {
            writer.Write(someText);
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really far away from what I am asking for. Really far away. I am just making an example of file opening in the class. I can have a database connection where I keep calling stuff on the connection in the lifetime of my object and then after my object dies I want the database to close. If my object was not disposed or used in `using` then the connection will not shutdown. in  C++ once the object goes out of scope, the destructor will be called and connection will be automatically closed

Comment: The only place where you use _using_ is in combination with local variables and local scopes.  Compare to C++' automatical call of destructors. The _using_ statement would dispose the object in question -  recursively, as the Dispose-method disposes the Object's members. Compare to automatical destructions of members in C++. Sure, this involves you to watch out and ensure every Dispose-method is implemented properly and you use _using_ everywhere.

Comment: @Everyone, for database connection, the proper way to use it is "open the connection, perform a query, dispose it": :Net framework handle a connection pooling and will take care about not having to create a physical connection to db every time. You really need to try to stop thinking the c++ way and start thinking the c# way if you want to use the latter. As other have pointed out, the two are simply different, and requires different way of doing things.

Comment: @GianPaolo Looking at the `C++/CLI` implementation, it is really similar to C++ in the way the object is destroyed. When it goes out of scope, `GC.Collect` is automatically called, and so the destructor is called without the need of the user to call `Dispose` manually. That is what I really wanted.

Comment: @Everyone Why you are fighting against the need to call Dispose? if someone, coming to c++ from a C# environment, keeps saying: "I don't want the users have to call delete after they created instances with new. In C# I don't need it, why in c++ I have to?". Simplified answer: that's how c++ works, use smart pointers if you want make your life easier". Now reverse the paradigm, and use the right tool for doing it in C#: create IDisposable classes and your users will know they have to Dispose them at the right time. `using` will be helpful there.

Comment: @GianPaolo Well, most people got me wrong. All I was asking about was "how hard it is to achieve this, if intended" .. That's all I was asking about.